# Sendgrid multiple emails with different contentType?

Tags: php, sendgrid

Im trying to send multiple emails with Sendgrid, and everything works fine, unless i change Content type meanwhile.

Is it possible to change contentType determined which email im sending to?

The error:

> {"message":"If present, text/plain and text/html may only be provided once.","field":"content","help":null}]

Code:

```
    foreach ($emailAddress as $key => $email) {
        $addresses["$email"] = "$key";
        $perzon = new Personalization();
        $perzon->addTo(new To((trim($email))));
        $mail->addPersonalization($perzon);

        if ($email == "example@example.org" || $email == "iexample2@example2.org") {
            $mail->addContent(
                "text/plain",
                str_replace("   ", "", $messagePlain)
            );
            $mail->setSubject($subject);
        } else {
            $mail->addContent(
                "text/html",
                nl2br($message)
            );
            $mail->setSubject($subject);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you're re-using the `$mail` object each time you loop. And `addContent` _adds_ extra content to the email (clue's in the name!), it doesn't overwrite existing content. So by the time you're on the second email you could have added two lots of plaintext content (for example), and the mailing class can't cope with that because it doesn't know which version you really want to send. Is it really necessary to re-use the same $mail object through all the iterations of the loop? Why not just create a fresh instance each time? That would seem more logical, as each mail is unique.

Comment: Alternatively, why not simply send both types of content with every email? That's quite a common thing to do. That way you don't have to worry about whether the receiving mail client can read HTML or text emails - instead it's then up to that client (and its settings) to decide which version to display to the user.

Comment: @ADyson
The two special emails are meant to send to a Trello email, which doesn't like html in their description

- About reusing same mail object, im sure i was at their docs that's the way to send multiple emails most effecient, but yes, i could make a new one all the time, i guess that will do it for now :)

Comment: Will it reject or otherwise fail to read the email if it has HTML content _alongside_ plain text content? Or will it just ignore the HTML portion? Most mail clients will do the latter, if they don't support HTML.

Comment: ADyson, it will show all HTML tags inside the description as far i've experienced, maybe i did something wrong, but this was my working function, but it was only for single emails

Comment: Ok well then possibly you need to take the approach I indicated in my first comment - you didn't explain whether your re-use of the $mail object in each loop iteration is deliberately done for some other reason, or just a logical flaw which can be corrected as I suggested?

Comment: I guess just a logical flaw, as it's a function i wrote long time ago, and it worked as intended for single mails, and i had that understanding that you had one object, but multiple Personalization objects for each email.

Comment: ok. So basically wherever you are declaring the $mail object, I think you can move that line inside your foreach loop and that should help.

Comment: Also I'd expect you need to move the code which _sends_ the email inside the loop too, otherwise it'll only send once (using whatever was the last settings generated by the loop).

Comment: @ADyson
Yes, i figured that out after testing :-D 

It works now, so thanks :)

Comment: Great! I've written it up into a proper answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're re-using the `$mail` object each time you loop. And `addContent()` *adds extra* content to the email (clue's in the name! :-)), it doesn't overwrite existing content. So by the time you're on the second email you could have added two lots of plaintext content (for example), and the mailing class can't cope with that because it doesn't know which version of the plaintext content you really want to send - an email cannot contain more than one version of the same kind of content (because if it did, again the receiving client wouldn't know which version to display either).

So wherever you are declaring the `$mail` object (it isn't shown in your question), you need to move that line inside your foreach loop and that should resolve the issue, because you'll have a fresh instance of the email object each time, instead of keep adding things to an existing one.

Also I'd expect you need to move the code which *sends* the email inside the loop too, otherwise it'll only send once (using whatever was the last settings generated by the loop).